# Set Condition on checkbox, in android

Tags: java, android, checkbox

In my actiivty, i have created multiple checkbox items like this, where the text of checkboxes is coming from my SQLite db

```
finaldb.open();
            String[] db_data = finaldb.getdbdata(sensIds[i]);
            finaldb.close();
    for (int j = 0; j < db_data.length; j++) {
                        cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
                        cb.setButtonDrawable(id);
                        cb.setText(db_data[j]);
                        mainLayout.addView(cb);
                }
```

Now, i want to set a condition on my BUTTON that, if any of the checkbox is checked, activityA should be started or in other case activityB will be started.
I'm trying to do it like this,

```
if(cb.isChecked()) {

//ActivityA start 
}
else {

//ActivityB start
}
```

but its giving me IndexOutOfBoundExceptionError. Can anyone help me in the right direction?

EDIT:
When i remove my if else condition and works with only ActivityA, the code works perfectly fine, but when using this if else condition, it's only consider the else condition and start ActivityB every time.

Here is my logcat report,

```
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): Process: com.example.mydb, PID: 1138
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.example.mydb.FinalActivity.onClick(FinalActivity.java:219)
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-18 15:10:33.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This code is misleading... between String declaration and the loop is your SQL query, isn't it? Otherwise it is obvious that db_data has not been initialized!

Comment: cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext()); instead try  cb = new CheckBox(this);

Comment: @SuhailMehta have tried, it didn't work

Comment: @haywire,i have edited my question, check it now.

Comment: we need to see what happens inside "getdbdata"!

Comment: maybe the error here `sensIds[i]` that `i` is bigger than the array size

Comment: The problem is not in this code. Take a look at the stacktrace. What is on line 219?

Comment: @PauldeVrieze, Thanks for pointing at this. Now the error of IndexOutOfBOund which was at Line 219, has removed but still the code for **if else** is not working, its only running the else condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , if you have multiple checkboxes that belong to the same family and you want to apply condition that if any of them is checked ActivityA should start. 
You can try something like this,

```
  for (int i = 0; i < mainLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    if (mainLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof CheckBox) {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) mainLayout.getChildAt(i);
                        if (cb.isChecked()) {
                        //Start ActivityA
                            }
                        else {
                         //Start ActivityB
                         }
```

Comment: From your answer, i get a hint that i should set a boolean variable and set it true if any of the checkboxes is checked, then finally on the basis of boolean variable state , i can start my ActivtyA or ActivityB. But a liitle bit confused of how should i implement this?

Comment: Finally, with your answer help , i made my 'if-else' condition worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check `String[] db_data = finaldb.getdbdata(sensIds[i]);`

the error is almost certainly there

pay attention to the value returned by

```
.getdbdata(sensIds[i]);`
```

the error is relative to an `ArrayList` that has only 2 elements but your code try to access a element in position 2: a third element that doesn't exist.

Comment: You are right, there was problem with the ArrayList. The indexOutOfBoundException has now resolved, but m getting problem with my condition, every time i run the app , its only starting activityB and not considering my "if" condition

Answer (score 0):

@colonelcode , if there was problem with the button listener, then even ActivityB would not have started.                                                                                              P.S: don't have enough reputation to write this in comment, thats why i have to write it in a seperate answer.

Answer (score -1):

I agree, use breakpoints to check each iteration of the loop and see what the data is for each index. Perhaps there's an error in your getdbdata() method?

Are you still having problems with the Activity launching on checkbox check?

Comment: Yes, the problem has not solved yet. i have checked my query, everything seems to be fine but the error is still there

Comment: The IndexOutOfBounds or NullBoundExceptionError?

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: Try iterating the for loop -1 of db_data.length.

`for (int j = 0; j < db_data.length; j++) {
                        cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
                        cb.setButtonDrawable(id);
                        cb.setText(db_data[j]);
                        mainLayout.addView(cb);
                }`

Comment: There is something wrong with the if condition, because now the IndexOutOfBound error has removed, but when i'm running the app, its only showing me ActivityB, means its not considering my checkbox condtion.

Comment: How many checkboxes are there? Are you checking the state of multiple check boxes or just one?

Comment: As u can see, i have created checkboxes through loop, so there are multiple checkboxes approx 5 or 6 depends on query. i want to set condotion that if any of the checkbox is selected then ActivityA should start.

Comment: Does it matter which checkbox you are checking to call Activity B? Because from your code it looks like all the checkbox names are "cb". Also can I see your code in the button onClickListener?

Comment: @ColonelCode no matter which checkbox, condition is , if any of the checkbox is checked , the activityA should be started.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the button listener?